# Не выходит подключить owlCarousel в проект

Tags: jquery, webpack, owl-carousel

Сайт на Laravel, фронт собирается webpack'ом.

На странице с каруселькой ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

До этого часто использовал эту карусель на простых html проектах. Такая ошибка вываливалась только когда обращался к карусели до ее подключения.

Как подключал:

1) `npm install --save owl.carousel`

2) в app.js: `import 'owl.carousel';`

3) там же:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
});
```

Причем, если проинспектировать код страницы то сама карусель есть в собранном app.js как и ее подключение. Даже таймаутом подрубал ее секунд через 5 после загрузки страницы, все равно выдает эту ошибку.

Скелет наипростейший:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div>
        <a href="#tab1">Описание</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#tab2">Характеристики</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#tab3">Гарантии</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#tab4">Вопрос-ответ</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможно у вас селектор не работает.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос внешний вид скелета карусели. Селектор думаю тут не при чем.

Comment: Проверьте порядок подключения. owlCarousel должна подключаться после jQuery

Comment: тогда бы ругался на знак $, на этом сайте еще куча скриптов на jq, при этом они все подключаются в том же файле что owl и они работают)